# How to edit the email order template of OpenCart 1.5.6.1?

Tags: email, templates, opencart

I would like to ask, how I can edit the following email order template of Opencart version 1.5.6.1?

```
Subject: Gifts - Order 804

You have received an order.

Order ID: 804
Date Added: 22/04/2014
Order Status: Pending

Products
1x Mother of Pearl Rosary (RO-21) $26.00 1x Holy Water & Oil From Holy Land (HWC-01) $15.00 1x Rosary with holy earth (RO-12) $15.00 1x Box with Jerusalem Cross (BO-08) $14.00

Order Totals
Sub-Total: $70.00
UPS Ground: $12.67
Total: $82.67

The comments for your order are:

sacramental gifts for first communion
```

Now I want to add the name of the recipient at the top of the message, above the sentence "You have received an order", what I can do? What is the code I should add, and which files?

Please help me, I searched all Google and didn't find a solution !!

Comment: I recommend hiring an OpenCart developer.

Comment: Can you advice someone for me ?

Comment: i am specialist on opencart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/catalog/model/checkout/order.php

but all the texts are translates, then you need to change on this file:

/catalog/language/english/mail/order.php

Comment: Great, but what is the code to add: the first name of the recipient?

Comment: i dont know if i correctly understand, but you don't have the the user information disponible on the mail.tpl, you can analyze `/catalog/model/checkout/order.php` to see what is disponible on `$template->['data']`... but you have `$payment_address` and `$shipping_address` that have all infos, but formatted accordingly `payment_address_format` and `shipping_address_format`.

Comment: As you can see this example:

Subject: Gifts - Order 804

You have received an order.

Order ID: 804
Date Added: 22/04/2014
Order Status: Pending

I want to add this line "Dear Alexandre" .. what is the code i should add ?? I really can't find it :(

Comment: As i say, you cant do it direct on template, you need to do this on controller, it's very simple, but i think not so simple to you do... Try hire someone to do this for you.

Comment: Can you please help me with that? So I just only add the name of the recipient? or just give me your email and we can speak better to solve this problem, Please I need that.